# How to register multiple services inside a ServiceStack plugin?

Tags: servicestack

I read the new wiki [Modularizing Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services) on the ServiceStack page. What I don't find is how that I can register multiple services inside a plugin. Of course I can use `appHost.Register(typeof(MyServiceInside))` for each service inside the plugin. Is there a quicker way to add multiple services at once? Like you can in the constructor of the AppHost by specifying the assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegisterService allows you to register adhoc Services Manually. If you don't want to type the method out each time just use a For Loop:

```
var ServiceRoutes = new Dictionary<Type, string[]> {
    { typeof(AuthService), new[]{"/auth", "/auth/{provider}"} },
    { typeof(AssignRolesService), new[]{"/assignroles"} },
    { typeof(UnAssignRolesService), new[]{"/unassignroles"} },
};

foreach (var registerService in ServiceRoutes)
{
    appHost.RegisterService(registerService.Key, registerService.Value);
}
```

Comment: I marked it as an answer, although it was not what I hoped for :-) This solution is actually the same as typing the .Register(typeof(xx)) multiple times. But I understand it is not possible to add an assembly in the RegisterService as with the constructor of the AppHost. Thanks.